# Is there something like Statas xtline in R? Or: How do you quickly visualize a panel?

Tags: r

I find some of the Stata functions to quickly get an idea of what your panel is doing extremely useful. xtline is one. It gives you an overview of your variable in different lineplots: one for each country and all over time in one window.

It looks like [this](http://stats.idre.ucla.edu/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/xtline1.gif) and while it isn't fast, its very useful to check if some operation did what you think it did. Does anyone know if a package which does something like that exist? If not, what are your tricks?

Comment: The connection to your link times out on my end.

Comment: Yes it did. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simples:

```
dfr <- data.frame(id = rep(1:5, each = 20), time = rep(1991:2010, 5),
      variable = rnorm(100))
```

Equivalent of `xtline`:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dfr, aes(x = time, y = variable)) + geom_line() + facet_wrap(~id)
```

Equivalent of `xtline` with `overlay` option:

```
ggplot(dfr, aes(x = time, y = variable, group = id, color = id)) + geom_line()
```

Comment: oh wow. That simple. I knew about faceting but I didn't know the code could be so clear. Thanks! The last line is missing a bracket btw